# IntelliJ 14 will not allow me to edit XML text files

Tags: android, xml, intellij-idea

Hi I am in the process of creating an Android application for my final year project at university and am experiencing some issues. The problem is probably easy enough to solve but I just don't have the experience to figure it out!

The problem is that when I create an XML layout file I am unable to edit the **'text'** version. I can edit the 'Design' view with no problems but when it comes to linking buttons to different screens etc I am unable to go into the 'text' file and manually enter the code required to link buttons to screens.

So basically I have loads of different nicely designed and colourful XML files which correspond to the different screens in my application but I am unable to edit the text file which would in turn would enable me to link all of the screens together. When I go into the Text file and try to type, nothing happens at all!

I have recently upgraded to **IntelliJ 14** and never experienced this problem before. Any help would be massively appreciated!

*Thank You in advance!
Emma!*

Comment: I've never experienced that problem with IntelliJ but, if you like that IDE, have you considered using Android Studio instead (https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)? It's an Android development oriented IDE based on IntelliJ.

Comment: Unfortunately IntelliJ was the only IDE I had experience in using so I chose it at the beginning of the project. Since I am nearly finished the project I am not allowed to change the IDE however, I might be able to use an older version. Thanks anyway I will keep trying different things to see if I can get it to work.